# How to install ES6 in node/react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on my first node.js app and would like to use react with ES6.

I installed ES6 with npm install -g es6

I also installed the React package.

In my babel.js file I tried using

import gulp from 'gulp';

JShint states that ‘import’ is only available in ES6.

When I run gulp I get messages like:

Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

I am assuming the ES6 package is not recognized.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should provide your code, how you execute it, especially how you use bable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the best ways(under my opinion) to include ES6 support in node is to create a new file, for example, es6.js and use it to import babel and your server.js.

Something like this,

es6.js

```
require("babel-register");
require('./server.js');
```

If you want to use some additional stuff like ES7 features, you can create a .babelrc and load it like this.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

es6.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc');
var config;

try {
    config = JSON.parse(babelrc);
} catch (err) {
    console.error('==>     ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.');
    console.error(err);
}

require('babel-register')(config);
require('./server.js');
```